# Frida server keeps respawning

Tags: android, process, pid, frida

I have a frida server running on my phone. I want to stop it and start a different one.

Running `ps -A | grep frida` gives me the PID to kill.

```
root         19124  1064  132952  48396 poll_schedule_timeout 7b141fd0c8 S frida-server
root         19359     1   15560   2420 poll_schedule_timeout f25206e0 S frida-helper-32
```

I run the kill command `kill -9 19124`. It does kill the process, how ever the issue is that new one spawns.

```
root         23450  1064  149372  48344 poll_schedule_timeout 73400400c8 S frida-server
root         23466     1   15580   2256 poll_schedule_timeout f3aad6e0 S frida-helper-32
```

How can I stop the current frida server from running? I even deleted the `frida-server` from `/data/local/tmp` and restarted the phone, and the issue still persists.

Comment: Assuming that your phone is running Android is it possible that you have rooted it via Magisk and installed the Magisk frida plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have deleted the frida-server binary I don't think that the re-appearing frida instance has something to with that installation.

Assuming that your phone is running Android and you have rooted it using Magisk you may also have installed the [Magisk-Frida](https://Magisk-Frida) module which provides a frida-server instance that is started automatically after device boot.

Using the command `ps -Af | grep frida` you may see the process `busybox sh /data/adb/modules/magisk-frida/service.sh`. If this process is visible then the Frida server that is restarted after you kill it comes from this script. Disable or uninstall the Magisk module to finally stop frida-server.